# Last created 10 records from all of the 3 tables

Tags: t-sql

I have 3 tables

**Table1**

```
Primary_key  int
Forign_key  int
PostId
CreatedDate Datetime
```

**Table2**

```
Primary_key int
Forign_key int
LocationId
CreatedDate Datetime
```

**Table3**

```
Primary_key int
Forign_key int
UserId
OrganisationId
CreatedDate Datetime
```

How can I Select latest created 10 records from all of the 3 tables.
Note that the 3 tables have different structure

sql server 2005

Comment: What do you want the output to look like then?

Comment: I mean 30 rows or 10 rows? And what columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want "last 10 per table"

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        Primary_key, Forign_key,
        UserId, OrganisationId, NULL AS LocationId, NULL AS PostID,
        CreatedDate, 'table3' AS Source,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) AS rn
    FROM table3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Primary_key, Forign_key,
        NULL, NULL, LocationId, NULL,
        CreatedDate, 'table2',
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) AS rn
    FROM table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Primary_key, Forign_key,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, PostID,
        CreatedDate, 'table1',
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) AS rn
    FROM table
    ) T
WHERE
   t.rn <= 10
```

For "last 10 over all tables"

```
SELECT TOP 10
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        Primary_key, Forign_key,
        UserId, OrganisationId, NULL AS LocationId, NULL AS PostID,
        CreatedDate, 'table3' AS Source
    FROM table3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Primary_key, Forign_key,
        NULL, NULL, LocationId, NULL,
        CreatedDate, 'table2'
    FROM table2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        Primary_key, Forign_key,
        NULL, NULL, NULL, PostID,
        CreatedDate, 'table1'
    FROM table
    ) T
ORDER BY
    CreatedDate DESC
```

Comment: I just need 10 total;not per table. 10 latest records not per table