# ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified

Tags: t-sql

```
declare  @userid int
set @userid=9846
SELECT TOP 10 
          tagid, 
          [Description]
FROM   tagsuggestion 
WHERE  tagid IN (SELECT **DISTINCT** TOP 10  tagid
             FROM  (SELECT ulpt.tagid, 
                           createddate 
                    FROM   userlocationposttag ulpt 
                            WHERE  ulpt.UserID=@userid                                

                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT ult.tagid, 
                           createddate 
                    FROM   userlocationtag ult 
                             WHERE  ult.UserID=@userid
                    UNION ALL 
                    SELECT upt.tagid, 
                           createddate 
                    FROM   userprofiletag upt 
                             WHERE  upt.UserID=@userid
) T

             ORDER  BY createddate DESC)
```

The above query is  error ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

.but if i remove **DISTINCT** this query runs

I want to ensure the distinctness and i also want to keep the sort order  by createddate DESC

one of my associated post is

[Last created 10 records from all of the 3 tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438010/last-created-10-records-from-all-of-the-3-tables)

Comment: "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified" - you do realise that if, as you say, you remove the **DISTINCT**, that this phrase no longer applies... (X is required if Y is specified - and you've removed Y)

Comment: Also, what version of SQL Server?

Comment: So your first question was misleading for your *actual* problem?

Comment: @ Damien_The_Unbeliever : sql server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so we only care about each tag based on it's most recent created date, so we can structure the inner query as:

```
SELECT tagid,MAX(createddate) as createddate FROM (
SELECT ulpt.tagid, 
       createddate 
FROM   userlocationposttag ulpt 
WHERE  ulpt.UserID=@userid                                
UNION ALL 
SELECT ult.tagid, 
       createddate 
FROM   userlocationtag ult 
WHERE  ult.UserID=@userid
UNION ALL 
SELECT upt.tagid, 
       createddate 
FROM   userprofiletag upt 
WHERE  upt.UserID=@userid
) t
GROUP BY tagid
```

And then we can wrap that in another subselect, and apply the top ten:

```
SELECT TOP 10 tagid FROM (
SELECT tagid,MAX(createddate) as createddate FROM (
SELECT ulpt.tagid, 
       createddate 
FROM   userlocationposttag ulpt 
WHERE  ulpt.UserID=@userid                                
UNION ALL 
SELECT ult.tagid, 
       createddate 
FROM   userlocationtag ult 
WHERE  ult.UserID=@userid
UNION ALL 
SELECT upt.tagid, 
       createddate 
FROM   userprofiletag upt 
WHERE  upt.UserID=@userid
) t
GROUP BY tagid
) t ORDER BY createddate desc
```

And we no longer need distinct (because `GROUP BY` and `MAX` already ensured that each tag only appears once)

Answer (score 2):

You're basically telling the query to sort the output by a field that isn't there.

You must either put createddate in the select statement, or you could group by tagid,     [Description] AND createddate and order by createddate.

Now if you feel you may get duplicate tagids and descriptions when you include distinct createddate, then wrap another query around that and do your top 10 distinct on just those two fields.